# Partitions not detected by ubuntu 18.04 live usb

Tags: ubuntu, partition, grub, live-usb, gparted

I use a primarily windows system dual booted with my ubuntu 18.04
Since about 1 year, I was not able to boot up into ubuntu (initramfs prompt opens, and no solution I could find worked).
This original issue occurred after a BIOS update from windows.
So unable to solve the issue from grub directly, I decided to use boot-repair from a live USB. That is exactly what is did, and noticed the following irreguralities-

1. Boot-repair doesn't show any "recommended repair" option.
   So boot-repair should look like this -
   [image]

   But it looks like this for me -
   [image]
2. I am not able to detect any hdd partition whatsoever from the live USB boot. Things I tried-
   Gparted
   `sudo fdisk -l` (and loads of other similar commands)
   All of them show the pendrive itself as the only partition /dev/sda1

Now, detecting the partitions was important because I was doing what boot-repair does without boot-repair. But that requires mounting on the ubuntu partition etc, which is basically non existent according to the commands/programs

Also, this does not imply that my ssd has vanished somehow xD because I later booted into windows which was completely fine with all the files intact, and so was the ubuntu partition, alive and healthy.

Comment: My guess is that a suitable driver is missing. Use commands like `lsblk` do see if the SSD was detected at all. Also check the kernel startup messages for information about the disk. Assuming a PC with PCI bus, you may also find something with `lspci` - is the disk interface present?

Comment: lsblk , didnt work, i will try lspci.  

Also what do you mean by kernel startup messages? i am not well versed in this field , sorry for the ignorance

Comment: On Ubuntu, one method of viewing the kernel messages is `journalctl -k`.

Comment: Try a newer Ubuntu release

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thank you but that issue was solved, as mentioned in my answer, infact i am upgrading to 20.04 focal fossa as i am writing this comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved it myself, I had to change my ssd mode to AHCI in the BIOS Menu.
Boot repair worked fine, no boot issues anymore.

Comment: You said a year ago. Did Windows then update & update UEFI reseting UEFI to defaults which would turn AHCI back to RAID or Intel RST?